# Windows 10 Pro Creators update: Logitech G105 Keyboard backlight rapidly blinks when PC powered off

Tags: windows-10, logitech-keyboard

After the creator update (Windows 10 pro), my USB Logitech G105 keyboard is flashing/blinking rapidly when I shutdown the pc (I have fast boot turned off in Windows 10). When the pc is shutdown, if I unplug it and plug it back in then it stays unlit as it should.

Comment: Some USB ports are made to keep providing power even after the computer is turned off (for charging devices).  Have you checked to see if this happens on your computer?  Have you tried moving the cable to a new USB port and see if the problem persists?

Comment: I have not tried another port. This didn't happen prior to the creators update so I doubt a power to keyboard setting would have been affected by that since its bios related. I will double check that though.